# What is conscrypt ? Can you explain its usage with some examples?

Tags: java, android, jce, jsse, google-conscrypt

I need to use [Conscrypt](https://www.conscrypt.org/) in my Java application. I understand that it  implements parts of the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) and Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE).

What code changes are required to use it.

Comment: Doesn't that library have a documentation that you could refer to? Or how about asking the people that told you to use it?

Comment: I have linked the library page it does not have any examples, the team lead that suggested to use told about benefits of it but not the how part.

Comment: Try looking in issues, i found this:
https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/984
https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/982

Comment: just out of curiosity why you need to use that library? It doesn't look nice to use without a proper documentation

Comment: Well, if your team lead wants you to use it and you don't know it I'd suggest you ask him to give you an introduction or some documentation. Unless they want you to find it out on your own in which case they'd need to be aware of the additional effort (just a side note).

Comment: @Szprota21 I second that. Especially in the security domain I'd expect at least some documentation and be it "Here's the specifics for Conscrypt, for the rest grab documentation on JCE or JSSE". But not to add anything doesn't make it look professional (and I'd add thus not trustworthy for a security related library).